# How to access the members of a dynamic array of structures with pointers?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, structure, dynamic-memory-allocation

This is the main structure:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct CandyBar 
{
    char brand_name[30];
    float candy_weight;
    int candy_calories;
};

int main()
{
    CandyBar * snack = new CandyBar [3];

    return 0;
}
```

I managed to initialize the dynamically allocated 3 structures in an array of 3 elements.
I tried to access the structures via:

```
snack[0]->brand_name = "Whatever";
```

with no result, even with the other method:

```
(*snack[0]).brand_name = "Whatever";
```

I really have no clue, since I have been studying these for a couple of days.

Comment: Error: expression must be a modifiable lvalue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `snack` is an array of structures, just use `snack[0].brand_name`.

You also can't copy a string just by using `=` in C. Use `strcpy` instead:

```
strcpy(snack[0].brand_name, "Kitkat");
```

Comment: I discovered that assigning with = is illegal with membership operators, while legal in general i.e. char words[20] = { "Lots of words"};
Venturing into the esoteric corners of the language, thanks.

Comment: Actually, it's only legal when initializing `char[]` arrays (or when it is treated as `char *`).

Answer (score 0):

In C++, strings are arrays, and arrays cannot be copied using `=`. Try:

```
strcpy(snack[0].brand_name, "Whatever");
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, I had completely ignored I could include <cstring>

Comment: Should be 'string *literals* are arrays'.

Comment: You both answered at the same time, so I've accepted nneonneo's final answer because he answered the very first time, sorry.